# Restore .dmp file into csv

Tags: oracle, restore, mysqldump, csv, dump

We have asked our clients for certain data in a csv file format and we just got a `.dmp` file. I have been trying to open it using MySQL as if it were `.dump` but it doesn't work.

I have seen [other posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/restore-database-from-dmp-file) where they restore `.dmp` files with Oracle but I have 0 experience with Oracle (and very little with databases overall). Is there any alternative to get the contents of the `.dmp` file into a csv format?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. If that is a file generated by either the classic or Data Pump version of the Oracle export utility, it's a proprietary binary file format.

There may be third party tools that could read the **.dmp** file and produce a **.csv** file. But then you're evaluating tools, buying a tool, learning the tool, etc. On a one-off basis, it may be just as easy to grab the express edition of Oracle, restore it, and then generate whatever you want. Or to ask the customer to generate an actual CSV file.

Your basic options, assuming this is actually a file generated by the Oracle export utility (classic or Data Pump) would be to

1. find a third party tool,
2. install Oracle and import it there, or
3. ask the customer to give you a CSV file. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/555